# Clean way to get related entities based on selection

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using C# and EF 4. I have a Actor repository.  The entity Actor has many to many relationship with Movie.
So in the ActorReposity i'd like to have a method example GetActors whose salary is greater than 100 and also in the results i would like to include the movies that this actor has been in whose director is Doe.(director is property on the movie)
the signiture of the method i have in the repository is IQueryable GetActors(). In this case i am just simpifying the signiture, After i get this to work then i can refactor to pass in parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public class ActorRepository       
   {
       public List<Actor> GetActors(int minimumSalary, string directorName)
       {
          return _ctx.Actors
                     .Include("Movies")
                     .Where(x => x.Salary > minimumSalary)
                     .Select(x => new 
                             {
                                Actor = x,
                                Movies = x.Movies.Where(y => y.DirectorName == directorName)
                             })
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(x => new Actor
                     {
                        // copy scalar properties from anon to Actor, e.g:
                        ActorName = x.ActorName,
                        // then set the Movies  navigational property to the filtered type
                        Movies = x.Movies
                     }).ToList()

       }
   }
```

Comment: Hi! it didnt quite return expected results, it's  returning all director names..looks like the last where statement is not working properly.  Thankx

Comment: @user282807 - If you want *all* of the movies to be by that director, change `.Any` to `.All`. If that's still not what you want - perhaps reword your question.

Comment: the movies is a colllection property of actor, there is no x.Movies.Director, I tried x=>x.Movies.Any(p=>p.Name == "foo") this does not filter the collection I still get the Atcors and all movies instead of just getting the movies that has the director of name foo.

Comment: Is there a way to have just one where clause to query entity and related entity?

Comment: ok, i figured "Director" was a relationship on "Movies". Try `Where(x => x.Movies.All(y => y.Name == directorName))`;

Comment: I did try that also but still wont filter on the related entity. like y.Name == "foo" has no effects on the query.

Comment: I have read somewhere else that you cant use include to query related entities...It always includes all of the entities regardless of condition.

Comment: Yep, i see your problem now. Your right, Include will return all entities. What you need to do is a (somewhat dodgy) projection trick. I've edited my answer - note, your not going to be able to return `IQueryable`. Your going to have to execute the query. Besides, when you return IQueryable, it should be simple (e.g return ctx.Actors), not complex stuff like this.